# Angular: Issue with Fetching Property Details - Getting 'NaN' Error

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-boot

working on an School project of Angular application that interacts with a Spring Boot backend to display property details. http://localhost:8080/property/{propertyId}/details works fine and returns the expected JSON response for property details. When I navigate to the property details page in my Angular app and attempt to fetch property details using the property ID from the query parameter, I'm encountering an error displaying 'NaN' in the template.

[image]

Checked the backend API with tools like Postman and directly accessing http://localhost:8080/property/1/details, received the expected JSON response.

I have uploaded it on github.

https://github.com/s27mandal/property-search-app.git

Comment: `NaN` is produced probably with `+undefined`, with undefined being here somewhere: `queryParams: { id: property.property_id },` at: https://github.com/s27mandal/property-search-app/blob/2bf06520eb89e16866f9b046f0d6495a3c42e1ed/angular-app/src/app/property-search-results/property-search-results.component.ts#L78, check it, it's probably undefined, giving `NaN` when converted to number, probably typo, it should maybe be `propertyId` or something..